# Kotlin - How to set Non null Object value to null?

Tags: android, kotlin, null

Am getting response in my web service as below :

```
"data": [
        {
    myObject:{"key1":"keyValue1","key2":"keyValue2"}
}]
```

Now I have to make this myObject null. I am trying as below :

```
if (mMailModel != null && mMailModel!!.myObject != null)
{
    mMailModel!!.myObject = null
}
```

I must have to make the **myObject** null.

The line telling me that **Null can not be a value of Non null type**

I have declared it at above in activity as below:

```
private var mMailModel: MainModel.Data?=null
```

Any suggestion ?

**EDIT**

My model class is as below :

```
data class MainModel(
        @SerializedName("data")
        var data: ArrayList<Data>,
        @SerializedName("message")
        var message: String,
        @SerializedName("status")
        var status: Int
    ) {
        data class Data(
            @SerializedName("myObject")
            var myObject: MyObject)
            {
             data class MyObject(
                @SerializedName("key1")
                var key1: String,
                @SerializedName("key2")
                var key2: String,
             )
            }
       }
```

Comment: I see your `mMailModel` is nullable, but what about the `myObject` within `MainModel.Data`? You may want ot make that nullable too

Comment: can you please share MainModel class?

Comment: @Roland Yes it might be null sometime from web service response. as "myObject": null,

Comment: @NehalGodhasara Added Model.

Comment: @JaiminModi so declare it as nullable then, i.e. `var myObject : MyObject?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare Your Model Like this,

> var myObject: MyObject? =null

```
data class MainModel(
        @SerializedName("data")
        var data: ArrayList<Data>,
        @SerializedName("message")
        var message: String = "",
        @SerializedName("status")
        var status: Int = 0
    ) {
        data class Data(
            @SerializedName("myObject")
            var myObject: MyObject? =null)
            {
             data class MyObject(
                @SerializedName("key1")
                var key1: String = "",
                @SerializedName("key2")
                var key2: String = "",
             )
            }
       }
```

Comment: okay and then I have to take care for the myObject at each place instead of instance of MainModel. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please use below updated class:

```
data class MainModel(
    @SerializedName("data")
    var data: ArrayList<Data>,
    @SerializedName("message")
    var message: String,
    @SerializedName("status")
    var status: Int
) {
    data class Data(
        @SerializedName("myObject")
        var myObject: MyObject?)//changed here
    {
        data class MyObject(
            @SerializedName("key1")
            var key1: String,
            @SerializedName("key2")
            var key2: String
            )
    }
}
```

You can then assigned null value to myObject as below

```
mMailModel?.myObject=null
```

Hope it will helps!!